# choice_translation_domain not working in symfony 2.7

Tags: forms, symfony, translation, symfony-2.7

I just upgraded my project to **Symfony 2.7**. One of the features why I wanted to upgrade as soon as possible, was the `choice_translation_domain` option for form fields.

But somehow there are still more then 3000 warnings for missing translations.

Here is how I added one field where the translation is already handled by doctrine:

```
$builder->add('product', 'entity', array(
    'class' => 'MyProject:Product',
    'required' => false,
    'multiple' => false,
    'empty_value' => '',
    'choice_translation_domain' => false,
    'label' => 'label.product',
    'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
        return $er->createQueryBuilder('product')
            ->orderBy('product.title', 'ASC');
    },
));
```

In translation debugging, I still see, that Symfony tries to translate the already translated product titles.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that we overwrite the default `form_div_layout` from Symfony.

So I had to change our custom form layout `.twig` file in order to make the option `choice_translation_domain` work.

Comment: Can you please share your solution?

Comment: Be sure you do not overwrite the form rendering of doctrine. Wherever your main layout.html.twig is, be sure you have this in it:  {{ choice_translation_domain is sameas(false) ? group_label : group_label|trans({}, choice_translation_domain) }}